# Unable to run my MVC application in chrome/fire fox:

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can any one help me to resolve the below problem:

My mvc application is unabale to run on any website getting the error like "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect" .Please find the below screenshot for the same:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqP4k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WuO7.png)

I Also tried with below solution which i got :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcnNJ.png)

Thanks,
Akarsha R

Comment: edit your question so it can be understandable. thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual 2017 means that is difficult to solve the problem. Because google clients side are trying to solve it. So better to use **fiddler** for avoiding such issues.